# Angular2 Http Response error of RequestOptions

Tags: angular, arrow-functions

what is the difference between this two functions,

```
  getFeedContent(url: string): Observable<Feed> {
    return this.http.get(url)
            .map(this.extractFeeds)
            .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getFeedContent(url: string): Observable<Feed> {
    return this.http.get(url, function (res) {
      console.log(res) // and other statements... 
    }).map(this.extractFeeds)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

The first one works fine, but the the second one throws an error saying

```
Type '(res: any) => void' has no properties in common with type 'RequestOptions
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to use feedMe (https://www.npmjs.com/package/feedme) in my code, which parses the feed in the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

The second version is triggering an error because the second parameter of [Http get()](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html#!#get-anchor) or [HttpClient get()](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get) is expecting an options object such as [RequestOptions](https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions) (Angular 2.x) for setting headers, params, or similar. The second version is attempting to pass a callback for handling the async response rather than an options object. The error message is indicating it's expecting properties in line with [RequestOptions](https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions).

Setting headers with Angular 2.x Http would look something like:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl, options)
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);
```

Setting headers for Angular 4+ HttpClient would look something like:

```
http
  .get('/api/items/add', {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token'),
  })
  .subscribe();
```

Otherwise version one would be the effective way of using RxJS operator `map()` to transform the response as necessary and operator `catch()` to handle Http errors as you're application would need. It's not clear what you're attempting to accomplish in the second example, but you'd likely want to move those types of statements to chained operator `subscribe()` to handle the response when it's emitted in an async fashion.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: So I am attempting to use the feedme npm module, which has uses sax-js for xml parsing and clarinet for json parsing.  I want to do an http.get and the take that parsed object and send it to match. Do I need to call the parser in the subscribe chained operator....?

Comment: Yes, the Angular Http and HttpClient modules have a very specific API so you won't be able to use the callback in the way this library does it, as the library's example is using Node's Http get(). You'd need to likely use this parser library in subscribe() or use additional RxJS operators to await the completion of parser's "end" event.

Comment: what are the RxJS operator for the end of parser event. The Feedme parser  has the on end event..   parser.on('end', function() {
    console.log(parser.done());
  });

Comment: You could use [Subject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md). This would be similar to [component interaction using a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) in the documentation. You could emit values via `next()` for the created `Subject<Feed>` sources. I'd try that then create another question if needed. Thanks!